# send post requests of the image that is currently visible on the scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, uiscrollview

I have a simple with a button. When users click on it they can select several images and then see them on the scrollview by scrolling them.

Users can see only one image. To see another images they need to scroll.

Now i need to send post requests of the current image that is visible on the scrollview.

can anyone help me with that?

Currently i can send post request of the first image that has been selected by users. But when users scroll and then when they stop at some image, i need to send post request of the current visible image.

My method for displaying several photos on the scorllview.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    workingFrame = _scrollView.frame;
    workingFrame.origin.x = workingFrame.size.width*ButtonNumberTimesPressed;
    image=[info valueForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
    ButtonNumberTimesPressed++;
    [self.images addObject:image];

    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    [imageView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFill];
    imageView.frame = workingFrame;
    [_scrollView addSubview:imageView];

    workingFrame.origin.x += workingFrame.size.width;
    [_scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];

    [_scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(workingFrame.origin.x, workingFrame.size.height)];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Method for sending post requets

```
- (IBAction)uploadPhoto:(id)sender {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer new];

    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"HI": @"Hello"};
    [manager POST:@"http://requestb.in/1c69jt31" parameters:parameters constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
        [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image,0.5) name:@"FileUploadPost" fileName:@"image.jpg" mimeType:@"image/jpeg"];
    } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSData * data = (NSData *)responseObject;
        NSLog(@"Success,Response string: %@", [NSString stringWithCString:[data bytes] encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    }];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, I'd implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate`'s `scrollViewDidScroll:` method. In this method, I'd use the `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset` property to find out which image is currently visible (basing on coordinates of the `UIImageView`'s `frame' property). Using this way, each time when a user completed scrolling, you'll be able to find out a currently visible image and issue a proper POST request.

Comment: i have implmeneted scrollViewDidScroll method, but it does not show anything

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"scrollViewDidScroll");
    
}
is it the right way?

Comment: Have you set the `delegate` property for your `UIScrollView`? It would be helpful if you add to your question the code for the scroll view initialization and implementations of your `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.

Comment: @ Nikolay Mamaev correct me if im wrong, do i declare delegate property just by doing this?

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

Comment: Using this declaration, you just let the ObjcetiveC compiler know that your class (`ViewController`) conforms to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol, that's it. In order to bind your delegate (i.e. a class conforming to the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol, the `ViewController` in your case) to a `UIScrollView`, you must explicitly indicate that by assigning the `UIScrollView`'s `delegate` property to an instance of the `ViewController`. Just like this: `_scrollView.delegate = self;` (assuming this code is in the `ViewController`'s class).

Comment: hey, so it worked, i mean scrollViewDidScroll. 
Could you please write the method to find out which image is currently visible( that is based on the frame property) because i have no idea how to do that

Comment: From what I see from your original question, you add only one image to your scroll view, whereas you likely need to add all images. After you add all images, you'll be able to compare the current `UIScrollView`'s `contentOffset` with frames of `UIImageView`s added to the scroll view as subviews, and hence you will understand which image is currently visible.

Comment: Your code for configuration of an image view frame and scroll view's content size don't look right. I guess this is a different question concerning creating and configuring the UIScrollView. I think it'd be better if you create a new question for this (e.g. named 'adding multiple images to UIScrollView'). If I have answered your original question (about a way to post HTTP requests for a currently visible image) then I'd appreciate marking my answer as correct.

Comment: ofcourse, i would mark your answer as a correct one. I have figured it out how to get the index of the visible image with scrollViewDidEndDecelerating. However, can i do something like this? 

        [formData appendPartWithFileData:[self.images objectAtIndex:indexOfPage] ];

self.images is the mutable array of the images. Indexofpage is the current index of the page visible. When im trying to upload it, it gives me "signal SIgabart, thread 1" Any idea why it is happening?"

Comment: Unfortunately the info you've provided is not enough. General answer is yes, you can. Could you please provide more details on this: the code mentioned above with the `appendPartWithFileData"` method, code for initializing the `self.images` array and adding objects to it, and console output for the exception? It would be great if you ask a new question - this question is becoming '100 questions in one' thing. If you post here a link for the new question then I'll take a look into it. Thank you!